# MongoDB, Updating a capped collection

Tags: mongodb, nosql

does anyone know a way to update a capped collection in Mongo3.2?  I had this working in 2.x where by I updated a collection, and basically removed all its content so I knew it had been processed.  This would then age out.

When I do the same in 3.2 I get the following error on the command line.

Cannot change the size of a document in a capped collection: 318 != 40

Here you can see I'm shrinking the document from 318bytes to 40bytes.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: can u show me ur query with which ur resizing and result of db.yourCollection.totalSize()

Comment: So the output of the command is as follows

db.metrics.totalSize()
196608

The command itself Is actually being called from a Python Script.  But it would have a similar effect to 

db.metrics.upate({"_id":<something>, "NewTime":<New Time>})

This previously worked in 2.x so I'm confident that the syntax is correct.

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned in mongodb docs

> Changed in version 3.2.
>
> If an update or a replacement operation changes the document size, the
>   operation will fail.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/capped-collections/

So your operation is changing the size of the capped collection, which is not allowed in mongodb 3.2+

Answer (score 3):

Shrinking a document in a capped collection is no longer allowed in 3.2. I did not find anything related to this in the documentation, but there is a rationale at https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-20529 
(basicalling shrinking document cannot be rolled back)

Your only option is to find a same-size update, for example update a boolean.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 3):

Capped collections are fixed size Collections. Hence it fails when the record update exceeds it's previously allocated size.

Changed in version 3.2.

If an update or a replacement operation changes the document size, the operation will fail.

For more information, Please visit the link: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/capped-collections/

So, the solutions is create a new Collection without choosing the capped one ( if this fits your requirement ). It works.

Answer (score 1):

**[Solve]** It's work with me

Create new Collection not Capped and copy all your document.

Copy, replace your collection name and paste in your terminal.

```
// replace <mycol> by <your collections name>
db.createCollection( "mycol_temp")
var cur = db.mycol.find()
while (cur.hasNext()) {
 mycol = cur.next();
 db.mycol_temp.insert(logItem);
}
db.mycol.drop()
db.mycol_temp.renameCollection("mycol")
```

Now, update() or remove() document is accepted.

Comment: This is not really an option in a production environment where your collection could be huge.